# Ubuntu 13.10 - driver for Dymo labelwriter 450 fastest printer

Tags: drivers, 13.10, kernel, printing, configuration

I have this super fast label writer printer which works perfect in Windows 7 but i need to use it in `Ubuntu 13.10` because my Python software is only Ubuntu 13.10 compatible.

But when i do printing it does not find the printer.

lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0922:0020 Dymo-CoStar Corp. LabelWriter 450
```

Downloaded driver:

```
$ get https://dymo.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/101/~/dymo-drivers-and-downloads#lw_mac
$ apt-get install libcups2-dev
$ apt-get install libcupsimage2-dev
$ ./configure
$ make && make install
```

Test Print:

http://www.labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/samples/js/PrintLabel/PrintLabel.html

Fails

Answer (score 1):

```
some command examples:

- print very long text on a tape:
lpr -o landscape -o PageSize=24_mm__1___Label__Auto_ docs/test.txt

- set printing options specific to the LabelWriter driver
lpr -o PageSize=30252_Address -o PrintQuality=Graphics -o PrintDensity=Light docs/test.txt

- set printing options specific to the LabelManager driver
lpr -o PageSize=Address_Label -o CutOptions=ChainMarks -o LabelAlignment=Right -o TapeColor=1
```

WORKS

```
$ lpr -o landscape -o PageSize=24_mm__1___Label__Auto_ docs/test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Printing from JavaScript isn't supported actually by the DYMOLabel JavaScript framework in Linux because it needs the DYMO label software which is not available for Linux. That's the reason the page to test your setup didn't work. 
You can follow their developer blog to see if they add Linux support in the future -> [Blog](http://developers.dymo.com/)

Comment: That is very BAD of Dymo, EVIL. Nobody makes Drivers for Linux even manufacturer's like we do not exist. I am personally only Linux user, i really dislike a hardware do not make Linux compatible drivers first and then consider other OS's.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But it's getting better, more and more companies are working on their Linux support. The printer driver of Dymo worked without problems, but I'm also upset they don't support JS-printing for Linux.